Strange behaviour with CustomTkinter widgets and drag and drop, using tkinterdnd2
I started looking at Drag and Drop with Tkinter, and based on answers, I produced UPDATE 2 of this previous question here. I also referenced this answer.
Based on these I produced this, obviously unfinished, piece of code:
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter
from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, DND_ALL


class CTk(ctk.CTk, TkinterDnD.DnDWrapper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.TkdndVersion = TkinterDnD._require(self)


class DnD():
    """Drag and Drop management class, used to drag one widget over another, target widget.
    The target widget then takes on the colours of the dragged
    widget."""
    payload = ['', '']

    def __init__(self, widget, enable_drag=True, enable_drop=True):
        self.widget = widget
        root.update_idletasks()

        self.widget_x_restore = widget.winfo_x()
        self.widget_y_restore = widget.winfo_y()

        if enable_drag:
            self.widget.drag_source_register(1)
            self.widget.bind("<Button-1>", self.drag_start)
            self.widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drag_motion)
            self.widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.restore_position)
            DnD.payload = [self.widget.cget('fg_color'), self.widget.   cget('hover_color')]

        if enable_drop:
            self.widget.bind("<<Drop>>", self.drop)

    def drag_start(self, event):
        """The drag_start method is a callback function bound to a mouse action (Button-1 click)."""
        widget = event.widget
        widget.startX = event.x
        widget.startY = event.y
        print(f'Dragging...')
        # widget.lift()

    def drag_motion(self, event):
        """Callback method, used in binding to mouse pointer motion, causing the dragged widget motion."""
        widget = event.widget

        x = widget.winfo_x() - event.x
        y = widget.winfo_y() - event.y
        widget.place(x=x, y=y)

    def drop(self, event):
        """Register a widget as a drop target."""
        target_button = event.widget  # Access the target button
        if isinstance(target_button, ctk.CTkButton):
            fg_colour, hover_colour = DnD.payload
            target_button.configure(fg_color=fg_colour, hover_colour=hover_colour)  # Change target button color

    def restore_position(self, event):

        self.widget.place(x=self.widget_x_restore, y=self.widget_y_restore)
        root.update_idletasks()  # move top widget (source widget), to access widget below (target widget)

        x, y = event.widget.winfo_pointerxy()
        target = event.widget.winfo_containing(x, y)

        target.event_generate("<<Drop>>")


class App(CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = App()
    root.geometry("600x400+200+100")
    button1 = ctk.CTkButton(root,
                            text="button1",
                            fg_color="red",
                            hover_color="red",
                            width=100,
                            height=50)
    button1.place(x=10, y=100)

    button2 = ctk.CTkButton(root,
                            text="button2",
                            fg_color="blue",
                            hover_color="blue",
                            width=100,
                            height=50)
    button2.place(x=200, y=200)

    # Register the buttons for drag and drop.
    button1_dnd = DnD(button1)
    button2_dnd = DnD(button2)

    root.mainloop()

The problem is that when I click into and try to drag a button, instead of the button moving, it shrinks or disappears.
Has anyone experienced and worked around this?
Thanks.

customtkinter.CTkButton is actually a tkinter Frame with Canvas and Label widgets inside.  The binding is on the two internal widgets, so the outcome is not what you want.  It is hard to do what you want.
